# Rails 3.1 Routes with fixed structured params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, http, routes

I have an sms gateway which pushes me get-requests if a user replys an received sms.

```
# gateway pushes following fixed style get-params 
# to my server/reply_from_gateway-action: ?id=123456&answer=Test

# => http://myserver.aaa/reply_from_gateway?id=123456&answer=Test
```

And now I want to add following route, since the sms gateway has a defined get parameter structure:

```
get "deactivate_via_sms?id=:id&answer=:answer" => "reminders#deactivate_via_sms"
      :as => "deactivate_via_sms"
```

But that doesn't work, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull CGI-style parameters out of `params` by hand in your controller, you don't need (or want) them in the route:

```
get "deactivate_via_sms" => "reminders#deactivate_via_sms", :as => "deactivate_via_sms"
```

and then in `RemindersController#deactivate_via_sms`:

```
def deactivate_via_sms
    id     = params[:id]
    answer = params[:answer]
    #...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can pull CGI-style parameters out of params by hand in your controller, you don't need (or want) them in the route

but in this case you can't use helpers such as

```
deactivate_via_sms_path(id,answer)
```

or you can use this code for creating helper

```
get "deactivate_via_sms?id=:id&answer=:answer" => "reminders#deactivate_via_sms"
  :as => "deactivate_via_sms"
```

but your routing will fail

I resolved this issue by changing "?" to "/" in route

```
get "deactivate_via_sms/id=:id&answer=:answer" => "reminders#deactivate_via_sms"
  :as => "deactivate_via_sms"
```

routing works and helper method also works fine